# Eevee - how to do god rays emitting from a transparent object?

Tags: animation, particles, eevee-render-engine, emission

Alright, Im trying to emulate the god rays/light streaks emitted from an explosion like this, in 2.8 eevee -

[image]
[image]

Ive looked at typical tutorials like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQooOGayOQI and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8wLd4Lob-o but these all deal with opaque objects to filter the light source.

I have a series of transparent bubbles that comprise my explosion - upping the intensity on a point light does nothing for this.

How can I accomplish god rays out of an explosion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this also involves the use of opacity to obscure the light, but unfortunately, that is one of the limitations of EEVEE. You can't apply masks directly to lights using nodes like in Cycles. However one way you could do this is to give the sphere itself a semi transparent texture, and then shine a light through it, capturing the rays with a volume.

Start with a sphere and give it a texture with transparent "holes". I used a Noise Texture, clamped with a ColorRamp to make this texture, and since it's black and white, I also used it as an alpha factor. As you can see on the right, I set the Blend Mode to Alpha-Clip.

[image: HoleTexture]

Next, add a cube, roughly the size of the desired "explosive radius", and give it a volume with a Volume Scatter node. You may want to adjust the density to meet your needs.

[image: VolumeCube]

Then, just place a point light at the center of the sphere. You can make the "god rays" look cleaner and more defined by adjusting the Volumetrics settings in the Render Properties panel. You can change the color of the light as needed. However, there are some limitations to the volumetrics in EEVEE - as you can see, the rays hit the edge of the cube in a rather noticeable fashion. You can make the cube bigger, but then the volume density can become more noticeable. You may have to spend time adjusting things until it looks tight in your scene.

[image: VolumeLight]